# compiler complains on onClickListener()

Tags: android, android-button

I am just starting on android programming. While trying out something the compiler is complaining on this:

```
Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01mainOk);
button1main.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Blah
    });
```

The compiler complains `The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new onClickListener(){})` but I checked `Google` for examples and I found a couple of them using the same as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01mainOk); 
button1main.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) 
    { 
        //Blah 
    });
```

I always do like this, but not 100% that the problem is this.

Comment: There is something funny going on. When I did what you told, it still complained on the `View.onClickListener()` and then it gave me a fix to remove `View` and not its back to the original but there are no red lines. Any explanations?

Comment: There's also a DialogInterface.OnClickListener perhaps you were importing this before.

Comment: I am not sure whats happening there :) Anyway, does it work now? It would be quite weird..

Comment: The warning are gone. :) But the program crashes `onClick()` :P. Thanks!!